# I want to change some things in a library it is called .hannesdorfmann:swipeback

Tags: java, android, swipe

I want to change some things in a library it is called .hannesdorfmann:swipeback
first I added :
    implementation 'com.hannesdorfmann:swipeback:1.0.4'

this library into my android studio
now I have a problem :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXMVR.png)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SwipeBack.attach(this, Position.LEFT)
            .setContentView(R.layout.activity_mahsol_activity)
            .setSwipeBackView(R.layout.swipeback_default);
```

I want to remove this.
can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As docuements say did you try these lines of code and  change them to false ?

```
.setDrawOverlay(true)
        .setDivider(drawable)
        .setDividerEnabled(true)
```